# box Collider falling through other box colliders unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a table made out of three cubes (top, two sides). Each has a box collider. The are all children of an empty object. The empty object has a rigid body.

I have a pallet with a package on it. The the package is a single cube with a box collider. The pallet is four cubes (top, 2 sides, bottom), each of which has a box collider on them. Both the package and the pallet or child of an empty that has a rigid body.

In my game, I have a forklift that lifts the pallet up (fork is a box collider that fits in between the box colliders on the pallet) and places it on the table. When the pallet is placed on the table, it falls through.

I had set "is kinematic" on all the box colliders as per a suggestion on another question in the forum. It worked for initial game state when the pallet starts sitting on the table, but if the pallet is dropped or placed on the table in the game, it falls through.

How do I keep the box colliders from falling through each other?

--- after feedback asking for more details ----

There is no code associated with the objects penetrating each other. There is a vehicle in the scene (a forklift), and there is script attached to it to move the vehicle and raise/lower a fork, which lifts/lowers the pallets seen in the images below.

Here is an image of the sequence. Sequence shows initial shape of package on pallet. Package has its own box collider same size as package, pallet is for box colliders (top, bottom, left, right). Third (top, right) shows initial penetration of pallet through shelf. Fourth (bottom, left) shows bottom of package penetrating bottom of shelf, pallet went completely through.

[image: image of sequence]

Comment: You should include code if it is helpful, of things you have tried. In your case pictures of what you are trying may help others understand it better. As for your question you should have a rigidbody on one of the objects that are colliding - one of the actual two colliding not empty objects that are not involved.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out the answer.
The box colliders need to have a realistic amount of mass. Mine were set to whatever the default mass was for the object, making the collision detection unpredictable. Once I assigned a larger mass (whatever one would expect for a fork on a forklift... I assume this was more than the true necessary minimum) it started working predictably.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing code or visuals, but the first easy thing to check is make sure the colliders are not checked as a trigger.